# MySQL SHOW COLUMNS unexpected behavior

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have the following PHP code:

```
$res = mysqli_query($this->get_connection(),"SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->get_table());
$mat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
var_dump($mat);
```

The connection is OK and it is returning data, so we can skip this part.

The problem is that, as I understand, SHOW COLUMNS should return one line for each column in my table. But when I run this code against tb_categoria, whose description is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_categoria` (
    `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'CHAVE DA TABELA',
    `descricao_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'NOME DA CATEGORIA (PRODUTO)',
    `situacao_categoria` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'SITUACAO DA CATEGORIA ( 0 INATIVO - 1 ATIVO)',
    `imagem_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'IMAGEM PRINCIPAL DA CATEGORIA (PRODUTO)',
    `legenda_categoria` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LEGENDA DA CATEGORIA (HOME)',
    `resumo_categoria` text COMMENT 'RESUMO DA CATEGORIA (DETALHE)',
    `ordenacao_categoria` int(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ORDEM DA CATEGORIA',
    `description_categoria` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `keywords_categoria` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `title_categoria` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`),
    KEY `situacao_categoria` (`situacao_categoria`) USING BTREE,
    KEY `descricao_categoria` (`descricao_categoria`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=193 ;
```

it returns information just about 'id_categoria', the first column.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop to traverse through all the columns.

```
    $res = mysqli_query($this->get_connection(),"SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $this->get_table());
   while($mat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    var_dump($mat);
   }
```

Comment: It didn't help, @Tarun. I had already done that. But when I do this, the second call to mysql_fetch_asson returns an error, as it the lines had ended.

Comment: Can you let us know what was the error you faced? I did run the same code and got the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had explained that. As Sinatra would say, "let me try again": 

It returns just ONE row, i.e., just the description of the first field of the table. And when I go through it with the loop you suggested me, it happens exactly the same, with a single difference: from the second call on it says $res is not a valid result.

Comment: Your answer is ok. It just fails in one thing @Tarun. Notice that inside the while loop use wrote mysql_fetch_assoc, not mysqli_fetch_assoc. Then it was saying to me it couldn't use an object type. If fact, mysql functions receive a result pointer, while mysqli functions receive an object. Except for that, you loop solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind to edit your answer, @Tarun, and change mysql to mysqli inside the while loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend @Tarun. You saved the day!